# unable push modified content

Tags: git, push

Here is my problem:
I used to push into [github.com](http://github.com) several folders, but two of them was empty. When i try `git status`, it shows me

On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
<
use "`git add<file>`..." to update what will be commited>
<
use "`git --chackout<file>`..." to discard changes in working derictory>
<
commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules>

modified:app/model (modified content)
   modified: app/show (modified content)
no changes added to commit (use "`git add`" and/or "`git commit -a`")

My local folders are not empty, just in remote. How can i add files from these folders into remote repo?

p.s. i tried `git add -A .`, `git add -u`, `git add .`, `git submodule --recursive git add -A .`, `git submodule --recursive git commit -a -m "Initial commit"` but it doesn't help.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: have you tried "git add ." or "git add -u"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/1615903 - is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

Start `git gui` and click files to stage. Or use the 'Stage changed' button.

Answer (score 1):

I can't quite make out what you're trying to say.  Are the folders still empty, or is there content in them now?

Git doesn't track folders, it only tracks files.  So you can't add an empty folder into the Git repo, if that's what you're trying to do.  If you really want the directory there, the standard practice is to add an empty `.gitkeep` file into it, so that Git has some content to track there.  Then you would `git add foldername` and commit it.

Comment: Sorry for that.
There is a content in them - in each folder a few files. I can't add files in them in repo.

Comment: Are they submodules?  Do you have any submodules in your project?  I'm just curious if you sent something further awry using `git submodule`.

Comment: actually, yes. It was bad and unnecessary idea to use `git submodule`.